# Как скрыть див при прокрутки скролл на вниз? А вверх показать?

Tags: javascript

Как скрыть див при прокрутки скролл на вниз? А вверх показать?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  background: #555;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
Fixed Div
</div>
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@mariusc23/hide-header-on-scroll-down-show-on-scroll-up-67bbaae9a78c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используем событие `window.onscroll`

```js
var oldScrollY = 0;
var div = document.getElementById("fixedDiv");

window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var dY = scrolled - oldScrollY;
  
  if ( dY > 0 ){
    div.className = "fixed fixed-bottom";
  } else {
    div.className = "fixed fixed-top";
  }
  
  oldScrollY = scrolled;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}
    
.fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25px;
  background: #555;
  position: fixed;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: bottom .2s ease-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: bottom .2s ease-out 0s;
  -o-transition: bottom .2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: bottom .2s ease-out 0s;
}

.fixed-top{
  bottom: 0;
}

.fixed-bottom{
  bottom: -75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixedDiv" class="fixed fixed-top">
    Fixed Div
</div>
```